# Jasper Printing not Printing Properly

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I am trying to print the jasper report from my j2ee application without viewing . i am using 80*297mm paper for printing but the alignment are mismatching,my code is given below

```
String s1 = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(reportFile.getPath(),
                                               param, conn);

JasperPrintManager.printReport(s1,true);
```

how can i give alignment in java code

Comment: post what have you done so far

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You can use the param Map object to pass parameters from Java to the report, and use the parameters accordingly in the report.

Comment: i added the parameters already ,report is coming fine ,but the problem is with alignment

Comment: Is there any way to align printing pages in java code

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, i change the default page size in jasper when designing the page,thermal printer page size is 80*278 ,so i set this page size to jasper report